# Inequalities in triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $D$ be the midpoint of the side $BC$ of triangle $ABC$. Prove that if $AD > BD$ then angle $A$ is acute; else if $AD < BD$, then angle $A$ is obtuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
|AD|>|BD|=|CD|
$$

implies
$$
\angle (BAD) < \angle B \quad \mbox{and} \quad \angle (DAC) < \angle C
$$
Summing them up you have
$$
\angle A < \angle B + \angle C
$$
Hence $A$ acute. The other direction is similar.